# PhoneGap Hello World change orientation

Tags: cordova, orientation, landscape

This is silly, but if I run phonegap create someApp, and then edit the config.xml file from:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
```

to

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

and run on ios, nothing changes.  In fact, its locked in portrait mode.  Whats up with this?  This is a fresh app, no modifications.  Documentation says that this is all there is to it, but it does nothing.  Not finding any help anywhere else online...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having exactly same issue - both cordova and phonegap 'hello world apps' with a single line of modification (as mentioned above) fail on iOS Emulator :(

Comment: just checked - works like charm in Android Emulator :(

Comment: I'm actually trying it on an iPhone 5s, so that means emulator AND real hardware both ignore this setting... I would love it if someone who has figured this out could enlighten us.

Comment: actually you can set orientation in xcode when open your ios project that can be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation for possible solution.

I have updated the js/index.js file from the default app:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape'); //this is the new line
},
```

This is just a workaround as now the app works differently on Android and iOS :(

Comment: getting rid of some meta tags (as advised for iOS7) fixed the different layout issue on Android/iOS with the use of above plugin.

 <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->