# iOS Cordova Xcode Project Settings vs config.xml for Landscape Orientation?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I tried setting the line:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

in my config.xml file, but it doesn't work (afterwards I tried doing 'cordova build ios' in the command line but still didn't work. Instead what works is going to my project settings in XCode and selecting the orientation there.

But I'm wondering if this is the correct way? shouldn't everything be done in the config.xml file?

Comment: Have you tried it this way `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

is the correct way. Yet it fails :(

Check [PhoneGap Hello World change orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134485/phonegap-hello-world-change-orientation) for a solution I use rather than modify the XCode project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$ cordova prepare
```

Or:

```
$ cordova platform remove ios
$ cordova platform add ios
```